# Finding the most recent mails for each project using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph database connects `Project` nodes to `Mail` nodes by a simple `BELONGS` relationship. The `Mail` nodes have a `long` property called `sentDate`.

I'm trying to find the `n` most recent mails for each project.

My current query only finds the `n` most recent mails of all time, regardless of project:

```
MATCH (project:PROJECT)-->(mail:MAIL) RETURN project.projectId AS projectId, mail ORDER BY mail.sentDate DESC LIMIT somelimit
```

I'd like to return something like rows with per row: projectId and a list of the most recent mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
MATCH (project:Project)-->(mail:Mail)
WITH project, mail
ORDER BY mail.sentDate DESC
RETURN project.projectId, collect(mail) as mails
LIMIT 10
```

I assumed that you want to limit projects. If you also want to limit mails per project you'll write `collect(mails)[..10]`

Comment: Thank you, I got it working using `MATCH (project:PROJECT)-->(mail:MAIL) WITH mail, project.projectId AS projectId ORDER BY mail.sentDate DESC RETURN projectId, COLLECT(mail)[0..10] AS mails`